# HTML5 animation in canvas

Tags: html, animation, canvas

Is there other ways to animate an object moving in a canvas without the use of setInterval() or setTimeout()?

Reason is because it kinda lags as time goes by when using useInterval(). I got no idea why it lags also.

I tried removing the setInerval() and everything is ok with no lag but there is no animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there is other ways to animate an object moving in a canvas without the use of setInterval() or setTimeout().

Yes. There is also [requestAnimationFrame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/), but not on all browsers.

Additionally, try setting your interval to much smaller and much larger values and see if either make it less jumpy.

*Additionally,* make sure there is as little going on in your draw loop. It could be your own fault for the lag. Canvas is pretty sensitive to performance things, and its up to you to keep it running fast.

Comment: yep larger values for the interval kinda helps the problem. But the animation would be jumpy (not so smooth)

Comment: mmm yea. it might be due to the vast objects in the loop. thanks anyway :D

Comment: guess the only way to help the problem is to have larger intervals

Comment: If you post your code somewhere I can take a look at it and give you performance pointers

Answer (score 0):

Define lag, do you mean kinda jumpy? because if so your set interval is wrong, I have animated plenty of canvas using those two methods, and afaik there is no other way.

Comment: not that jumpy as the interval is short              setInterval(function() {
        draw();
    }, 100);

Comment: when i first run the web app it runs fine, but as time goes by, it starts to lag. like as if it is using alot of memory

Comment: what do you mean by recursing ?

Comment: in the loop, i will be clearing the current canvas then draw some images with onClick events and then set the new x,y to animate it.

Comment: and whenever i click the moving images, it seems to use more memory and lags.